# How to set margin between input tags in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two input elements on my page. I need to give margin between the two elements.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
```

I have created a class for assigning margin for the password input. I would like to know if there are better ways to do this? Perhaps by wrapping the two input tags with divs?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the margin way

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap, the right way is to do this way:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

If you are just interested in adding a space between them, here you go:

```css
.space-right {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control space-right" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
.form-control {
  margin:0 5px; // for left and right margin
  margin:5px 0; // form top and bottom margin
 }
```